# node.js/sqlite3 SELECT works from command line but not from JS binding

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

Using the command line sqlite3 utility:
I created a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
Security (
  userId        TEXT NOT NULL,
  totalHash     TEXT NOT NULL,
  accessType    TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (userId, totalHash)
);
```

Then insert 1 row.

```
insert into Security (userId, totalHash, accesstype) Values ('bill', '768caa1c468991cb0a0be1cf1d67f6783c56b529ef843e7e43870be1c75db9977c3cc0db6d4ea3a9c02ec542311180a49a85440ae1182dc6ab115ecdb240e208', 'login');

SELECT * FROM Security WHERE userID='bill' AND totalHash='768caa1c468991cb0a0be1cf1d67f6783c56b529ef843e7e43870be1c75db9977c3cc0db6d4ea3a9c02ec542311180a49a85440ae1182dc6ab115ecdb240e208' AND accessType='login' LIMIT 1;
userId      totalHash                                                                                                                         accessType
----------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                     ----------
bill        768caa1c468991cb0a0be1cf1d67f6783c56b529ef843e7e43870be1c75db9977c3cc0db6d4ea3a9c02ec542311180a49a85440ae1182dc6ab115ecdb240e208  login
```

JavaScript code in node.js to do the same SELECT:

```
if (debug) {console.log('userId=' + userId + ', totalHash=' + totalHash);}
Db.get("SELECT * FROM Security WHERE userID=? AND totalHash=? AND accessType='login' LIMIT 1", true, userId, totalHash,
   function (error, row) {
      if (error !== null) {
         if (debug) {console.log(error);}
         res.writeHead(401, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
         res.end('Invalid login');
      } else {
         res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
         res.end('Login OK');
      }
   }
);
```

Returns this:

```
userId=bill, totalHash=768caa1c468991cb0a0be1cf1d67f6783c56b529ef843e7e43870be1c75db9977c3cc0db6d4ea3a9c02ec542311180a49a85440ae1182dc6ab115ecdb240e208
{ [Error: SQLITE_RANGE: bind or column index out of range] errno: 25, code: 'SQLITE_RANGE' }
```

It works from the command line, but not via the JS to sqlite binding. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in second line.

```
 Db.get("SELECT * FROM Security WHERE userID=? AND totalHash=? AND accessType='login' LIMIT 1", [userId, totalHash],
```

Comment: That got rid of the error, but now its not returning anything. The row variable is always undefined. I even tried the named parameters approach and it also doesn't produce the error, but still produces no output. Of the 3 ways listed in the API to specify the call, my first attempt errors out and the two remaining ways produce no output. The fact that there's a difference seems to point to an issue with the binding code.

Comment: It does work in my pc. row = [object Object] when there is a match and row = undefined when there is no match.